# Android : Change the text color of a spinner item inside the dropdown list

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, colors, textview, spinner

How can I change the text color of a spinner item **inside** the dropdown list?

When I do (inside the **onItemSelected** method) :

```
((TextView) view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
```

or

```
((TextView) spinner.getAdapter().getView(position, view, parent)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
```

or

```
((TextView) spinner.getChildAt(position)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
```

or

```
((TextView) spinner.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
```

it changes the color of the spinner selected item, but not inside the dropdown list.

And doing this :

```
((TextView) spinner.getAdapter().getDropDownView(position, null, parent)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reach this goal setting up an adapter. You should create a custom adapter showing your items in a simple way.

[this is the official reference for adapters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). You can refer to this for any method or variable.

[this SO link has the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33405593/4700782).

So what you have to do is:

- Create a custom adapter
- Create the layout and the java code for the adapter (you can easily find on google thousands of examples
- Add the code from this (you will need to customize it for your needs.

**ADAPTER**

```
 class HighLightArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {
    private int mSelectedIndex = -1;

    public void setSelection(int position) {
        mSelectedIndex =  position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public HighLightArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, CharSequence[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView =  super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (position == mSelectedIndex) {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(56,184,226));
        } else {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

**PS:**

Since the `setSelection` method is not native, you need to call it from the `OnItemSelectedListener` in the activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fan of the easiest solution, I would have liked to change the color on the fly, without having to use a custom adapter. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Denis yeah I can understand, but unfortunatly everything different from the base layout, is possible to achieve but requires some code. btw creating an adapter is really easy. Some times ago I also was thinking it was annoying and I was trying everything to avoid it, but I changed my mind when I saw the adapter's power. Believe me, it is really easy and powerfull

Comment: I'm used to use adapters, but like most developers, I'm pretty lazy. By the way, this time you really helped me to find the required motivation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways to achieve this in android

1. **@Override ArrayAdapter** methods
2. Create **Custom Spinner Adapter**

Let me explain each approach with example :

1. **@Override ArrayAdapter** methods

Try to **@Override getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)** to customize or set **TextView** property as per your requirement.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      TextView textView = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
      textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
      return  textView;
}
```

Try to **@Override getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)** to customize or set **TextView** property as per your requirement.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       return  textView;
}
```

Worling example using **@Override ArrayAdapter** methods

```
spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
spinnerList.add("Spinner item 1");
spinnerList.add("Spinner item 2");
spinnerList.add("Spinner item 3");
spinnerList.add("Spinner item 4");
spinnerList.add("Spinner item 5");
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerList){
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            return  textView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            return  textView;
        }
    };
mSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Create custom spinner adapter

Try to create **Custom Spinner Adapter** :

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] data;
private int selectedItemColor;
private int itemColor;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, String[] data, int selectedItemColor, int itemColor) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.selectedItemColor = selectedItemColor;
    this.itemColor = itemColor;
}

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, String[] data, String label, int selectedItemColor, int itemColor) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.data = new String[data.length + 1];
    this.data[0] = label;
    for (int i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
        this.data[i] = data[i - 1];
    }
    this.selectedItemColor = selectedItemColor;
    this.itemColor = itemColor;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_selected_item, parent, false);
        holder.txtSpinnerSelected = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSpinnerSelected);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtSpinnerSelected.setTextColor(itemColor);
    holder.txtSpinnerSelected.setText(data[position]);
    return convertView;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down_item, parent, false);
        holder.txtSpinnerItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSpinnerItem);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtSpinnerItem.setTextColor(selectedItemColor);
    holder.txtSpinnerItem.setText(data[position]);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtSpinnerSelected;
    TextView txtSpinnerItem;
}
}
```

**spinner_drop_down_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/txtSpinnerItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

**spinner_selected_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/txtSpinnerItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

Working example using **Custom Spinner Adapter** :

```
String[] spinnerArray = new String[5];
spinnerArray[0] = "Spinner item 1";
spinnerArray[1] = "Spinner item 2";
spinnerArray[2] = "Spinner item 3";
spinnerArray[3] = "Spinner item 4";
spinnerArray[4] = "Spinner item 5";
CustomSpinnerAdapter customSpinnerAdapter = new      CustomSpinnerAdapter(this,spinnerArray,Color.RED,Color.BLUE);
mSpinner.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapter);
```